# Android concurrent popup hide/show with fade in/out

Tags: android

i'm trying to set alpha animation to `translate` to show and hide dialog as fade in/out, i tired to use this below xml animation, that have problem to fade in/out after `translate`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"/>
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"/>
</set>
```

how can i set fade in/out when dialog animation is on `translate`

Comment: " that have problem" and what is your problem?

Comment: @StealthRabbi fade in/out not concurrent with translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        />
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        />
</set>
```